# Routing to use Intranet LAN & Wi-Fi Both

Tags: windows, networking, router, internet, routing

Need to use Ethernet to access local network and Wi-Fi for Internet. Ethernet also has internet access, which isn't needed. Running Windows 10.

Read multiple articles. Changing priority with metrics doesn't allow both networks to be usable. Can only use Wi-Fi.

Came accross solutions by routing particularly  [Ethernet (intranet) and Wi-Fi (internet) to work simulatenously](https://superuser.com/questions/707623/ethernet-intranet-and-wi-fi-internet-to-work-simulatenously)
[Wi-Fi for Internet and LAN Domain Network - Multi-Sourced DNS Resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/628742/wi-fi-for-internet-and-lan-domain-network-multi-sourced-dns-resolution) (Used the 2nd answer)

My configuration is:

```
Wireless:
Default Gateway: 100.112.96.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.252.0

Wired:
Default Gateway: 172.16.122.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.254.0


===========================================================================
Interface List
  4...b8 81 98 7d 1b 8f ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
 10...b8 81 98 7d 1b 90 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  9...ec 8e b5 49 43 fc ......Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
 17...00 ff f6 7f 18 4f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 12...b8 81 98 7d 1b 93 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     100.112.96.1   100.112.98.101      3
     100.112.96.0    255.255.252.0         On-link    100.112.98.101    258
   100.112.98.101  255.255.255.255         On-link    100.112.98.101    258
   100.112.99.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    100.112.98.101    258
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        172.0.0.0    255.255.254.0     172.16.122.1   172.16.123.231     36
       172.16.0.0    255.255.254.0     172.16.122.1   172.16.123.231     36
     172.16.122.0    255.255.254.0         On-link    172.16.123.231    291
   172.16.123.231  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.123.231    291
   172.16.123.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.123.231    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    100.112.98.101    258
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.16.123.231    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    100.112.98.101    258
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.123.231    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     100.112.96.1       1
       172.16.0.0    255.255.254.0     172.16.122.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  4    321 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    321 fe80::6db3:1b53:13ba:4f35/128
                                    On-link
  9    291 fe80::a460:bc4e:1c8e:1ef1/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    321 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Wi-Fi metric is set to 2, for priority of course. After removing 0.0.0.0 route and adding the persistent routes (above)

I can access 172.16.0.30, which is the default Cyberoam login page which comes up to use Internet but can't use any other local addresses eg 172.16.xxx.xxx etc

I than also tried adding route for 172.0.0.0 obviously resulting no change

Edit: Apparently 0.0.0.0 for Ethernet allows access to the other local addresses apart from 172.16.0.30, adding and removing it also changes internet connectivity. Not feasible unfortunately.